# Accordion closes except when clicking icon

Tags: javascript, css, icons, accordion

I have the following accordion setup running. All running pretty well except for this tiny issue: once an accordion is open, you cannot close it by clicking the chevron icon. It will close anywhere else on the accordion but not on the chevron itself. Any idea why this happens and how this tiny but bugging issue can be fixed? Any guidance much appreciated. Thank you.

Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/oh823pxz/

```js
$(function() {

  $('.accordion .accordion-title').on('click', toggleAccordion);

  function toggleAccordion(event) {
  
   $('.accordion-item').not($(event.target).parent()).removeClass('is-open');
    var target = $(event.target).closest('.accordion-item');

    target.parent('.accordion').find('.accordion-item').not(target).removeClass('is-open');
    target.toggleClass('is-open');
  }
  
});
```

```css
.accordion .accordion-item {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}

.accordion .accordion-title {
  position: relative;
  padding: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.accordion .accordion-content {
  display: none;
  padding: 0 15px 15px;
}

.accordion .accordion-item.is-open .accordion-content {
  display: block;
}

.accordion .arrow {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
  top: 13px;
  right: 15px;
  background-color: inherit;
  border: solid #000;
  border-width: 0 2px 2px 0;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.accordion .accordion-item.is-open .arrow {
  top: 20px;
  transform: rotate(-135deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-135deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="accordion">
  <div class="accordion-item">
    <div class="accordion-title">
      TITLE 1
      <span class="arrow"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="accordion-content">
      CONTENT 1
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
  
 <div class="accordion">
  <div class="accordion-item">
    <div class="accordion-title">
      TITLE 2
      <span class="arrow"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="accordion-content">
      CONTENT 2
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-item">
    <div class="accordion-title">
      TITLE 3
      <span class="arrow"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="accordion-content">
      CONTENT 3
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this... z-index: -1;

```
.accordion .accordion-item.is-open .arrow {
    top: 20px;
    transform: rotate(-135deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-135deg);
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `.arrow` span does not respond to clicks, so trying to click on the arrow doesn't do anything.

One fix is to add `pointer-events: none` to the `.arrow` rule. Then the click passes through to the parent.

```css
.accordion .arrow {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
  top: 13px;
  right: 15px;
  background-color: inherit;
  border: solid #000;
  border-width: 0 2px 2px 0;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);

  /* prevents clicks */
  pointer-events: none; 
}
```

```js
$(function() {

  $('.accordion .accordion-title').on('click', toggleAccordion);

  function toggleAccordion(event) {
  
   $('.accordion-item').not($(event.target).parent()).removeClass('is-open');
    var target = $(event.target).closest('.accordion-item');

    target.parent('.accordion').find('.accordion-item').not(target).removeClass('is-open');
    target.toggleClass('is-open');
  }
  
});
```

```css
.accordion .accordion-item {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}

.accordion .accordion-title {
  position: relative;
  padding: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.accordion .accordion-content {
  display: none;
  padding: 0 15px 15px;
}

.accordion .accordion-item.is-open .accordion-content {
  display: block;
}

.accordion .arrow {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
  top: 13px;
  right: 15px;
  background-color: inherit;
  border: solid #000;
  border-width: 0 2px 2px 0;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  pointer-events: none;
}

.accordion .accordion-item.is-open .arrow {
  top: 20px;
  transform: rotate(-135deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-135deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="accordion">
  <div class="accordion-item">
    <div class="accordion-title">
      TITLE 1
      <span class="arrow"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="accordion-content">
      CONTENT 1
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
  
 <div class="accordion">
  <div class="accordion-item">
    <div class="accordion-title">
      TITLE 2
      <span class="arrow"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="accordion-content">
      CONTENT 2
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-item">
    <div class="accordion-title">
      TITLE 3
      <span class="arrow"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="accordion-content">
      CONTENT 3
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use CSS to fix a jQuery problem, this gets you into more problems if you are going to change your icon. I've edited the script a little and changed the logic a little. It should work now:

**Example code**
https://jsfiddle.net/s8w15bu7/2/

**HTML (added JS classes)**

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <div class="accordion">
  <div class="accordion-item js-accordionItem">
    <div class="accordion-title js-accordionTitle">
      TITLE 2
      <span class="arrow"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="accordion-content">
      CONTENT 2
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-item js-accordionItem">
    <div class="accordion-title js-accordionTitle">
      TITLE 3
      <span class="arrow"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="accordion-content">
      CONTENT 3
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS (I didn't change anything here)**

```
.accordion .accordion-item {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}

.accordion .accordion-title {
  position: relative;
  padding: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.accordion .accordion-content {
  display: none;
  padding: 0 15px 15px;
}

.accordion .accordion-item.is-open .accordion-content {
  display: block;
}

.accordion .arrow {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
  top: 13px;
  right: 15px;
  background-color: inherit;
  border: solid #000;
  border-width: 0 2px 2px 0;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.accordion .accordion-item.is-open .arrow {
  top: 20px;
  transform: rotate(-135deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-135deg);
}
```

**JS/Jquery**

```
$(function() {

  $('.js-accordionTitle').on('click', toggleAccordion);

  function toggleAccordion(event) {
    const classOpen = "is-open";
    let jqThis = $(this);
    let currentItem = jqThis.closest('.js-accordionItem');

    if (!currentItem.hasClass(`${classOpen}`)) {
        currentItem.siblings().removeClass(`${classOpen}`);
      currentItem.addClass(`${classOpen}`);
    } else {
        currentItem.removeClass(`${classOpen}`);
    }
  }

});
```